# Need helping adding Yes/No prompt to Fact template to iterate/ get another fact

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I am using the Fact skill template and I am modifying it so after reading out a random fact, it asks the user if they would like another. I've searched around on here, but similar problems seem to have a different syntax.

I don't know if I should be implementing this a different way, but I am unsure of what is going wrong in my code. I believe my issue is with .listen and if I should be using a .emit somewhere. (That was the way it was implemented in other examples)

I could be wrong, but as I understand it, my code is using the response builder whereas other people are doing it a different way.

Any help would be appreciated, If anyone could point me in the right direction to implementing it using this response buildier, it would help me out a lot.

I also have the built-in yes/no intents, but they aren't really doing anything right now.

```
const GetNewFactHandler = {
     canHandle(handlerInput) {
     const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
     return request.type === 'LaunchRequest'
       || (request.type === 'IntentRequest'
          && request.intent.name === 'GetNewFactIntent');
},
    handle(handlerInput) {

    const randomFact = data[i];
    const speechOutput = (GET_FACT_MESSAGE + randomFact + NEXT_MESSAGE)

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(speechOutput)
    .listen(REPROMPT_MESSAGE);
    .withSimpleCard(SKILL_NAME, randomFact)
    .getResponse();
   },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Change .listen() to .reprompt()

Comment: I've done that, but it still isn't working, and I have no idea why it isn't working, or what isn't working about it. I have searched for documentation or a guide or anything, but all I've found is one of the sample that implements the YesIntent almost exactly to what I have posted + the change you suggested.